# About nuclear shell model and number of excited states of a nucleus

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, potential

From our study of the finite square well potential, we know that only a finite number of discrete energy levels are bound. As the depth of the well increases, although more and more bound states are supported by the potential, it always has a finite number of excited states above the ground state.

Why doesn't this intuition work for potentials of finite depth but slightly complicated shape? For example, the shell model of the nucleus assumes a finite potential well of the Woods-Saxon type. How is it able to support an infinite number of excited states above the ground state $1s_{1/2}$?

Comment: As with all things quantum mechanical: 'follow the math'. Quantum systems with finite well depth, on calculation, always show a finite number of bound states. I believe very shallow wells may not show any bound states though...

Comment: @Gert Mathematical solution of finite square well in 1D shows that no matter how weak the potential is there is at least one bound state. By increasing the depth, the number of bound states can be increased but there is always a finite number of them as long as the depth is finite. But the solution of the Shell model with Woods Saxon potential seems to yield an infinite number of bound states. Why is that so?

Comment: *But the solution of the Shell model with Woods Saxon potential seems to yield an infinite number of bound states.* You have a reference for that?

Comment: Why do you think there are an infinite number of bound states for a Woods-Saxon potential?